# How do I ensure my android app will look the same on all android phones?

Tags: android, compatibility, clipping

Is there a truefire way to make sure my app will display the same on my Motorola Droid 2 as it will on other Androids?

I use nothing more than basic Linear Layouts, Image Views, Buttons etc - is there a good checklist to go by before I even think about launching an app?

Clipping issues, What SDK I should launch my app in, etc...?

Comment: read and adhere to advices in developer's guide, and do your test in at least QVGA, HVGA, 800x480, 848x480 and even 1024x600 (tablet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are following the guidelines for [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

You can use the emulator to experiment with the different possible screen sizes and densities, as described in that document under [how to test your app](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing).

Answer (score 1):

You can make emulator of different screen sizes to check your application.

One thing make sure you don't use "px"(pixels) anywhere in your application, use dp instead of px.